# Is it safe to fire custom "change" event in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, event-handling, dom-events

I've recently created a custom select-box component in Vue.js and wanted to trigger the `change` event whenever the user selects a value.

```
// SelectboxComponent.vue
<template>
    <!-- ... -->
    <ul>
        <li v-for="option in options" @click="select(option)">{{ option.name }}</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- ... -->
<template>
<script>
    export default {
        // ...
        methods: {
            select(option) {
                // ...
                this.$emit('change', option);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Which is then handled... `<select-box :options="options" @change="handle"></select-box>`

I'm wondering if these type of custom events are safe to use and will not create any conflicts with the native events. I've tested it in Google Chrome 67.0, which seems to separate the events correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Using `$emit`, you are firing an event from inside your component which can be listened by the parent component. This is different from native DOM Events.

And also, you can only use $emit from inside a `custom component`, and by default a `custom component` doesn't have a native `change` event.